# How to connect a Raspberry Pi to an RCA based display with sound?

Tags: pi-3, audio, display

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and a display that has only RCA as inputs. Please help me connecting the Raspberry Pi to the display so that I get both sound and visual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a display that has only RCA as output

I presume you mean 3 female *inputs,* 2 for audio and one for [composite video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video), which in North America are generally red, white, and yellow.

The 3.5mm jack on the Pi 3 can be connected to this as it includes a composite video line.  Jacks like that can be used with a normal 2 channel audio only cable, or a 3 channel one such as that shown below (the two ends are from the same cable).

[image]

Notice the three bands on the 3.5mm jack, one more than a standard stereo plug (these are actually separators as I believe in both cases there is an additional pole for ground, which is the sheath on the RCA end).  These are commonly available at electronic stores or online (search for a "3.5mm to RCA video cable").

Beware [as mentioned here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/07/raspberry-pi-model-b-3-5mm-audiovideo-jack/) (thanks Milliways) some of these cables are intended for camcorders and have one of the rings on the 3.5mm jack swapped; those will not work.  So don't get a cable that is intended for use with camcorders!

Comment: I am far from clear that this is what the OP is asking. There are 4 connections, and most of the commonly available cables are unsuitable. See http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/07/raspberry-pi-model-b-3-5mm-audiovideo-jack/

Comment: @Milliways Yes, as I point out in the last paragraph the visible rings (sometimes black) are *separators* and there are actually 3 channels on a normal 3.5mm jack, one for ground, hence *4* for video, **exactly as described in the link you provided, and the cable shown there is exactly the same as the one shown here.**  There is another form of video using RCA connectors that is 3 channels for video (instead of one) and 2 for stereo, but this is much less common (and I suppose not compatible with the pi).

Comment: I will edit in the bit about the camcorder cables, but I would presume those are the exception and not the rule.

Answer (score 2):

To be sure, you can get a cable from [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2881) to ensure that the cable is for RCA display product (versus RCA output product).

Answer (score 0):

I am running a raspi B+ running retropi for a retro game station in my mancave and I have a dinosaur TV that only has RCA. I ordered a cable from Adafruit and it works like a charm. Cheapest and best one out there: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2881

All you do is plug it into the audio jack on the raspi and then into your RCA and you're set!

It's a great alternative to HDMI to RCA converters. Much less hassle.

Good luck!